# Populate user defined objects from a list from the JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

In my Action class, I have a List of `Questions`. that I would want to be populated from the view.

```
public class MyQuizTest extends ActionSupport {

    public String addItemsToTemplate(){
         List<Question>  q=  myQuestions;
         System.out.println(q);

         return "success";
   }

    public List<Question> getMyQuestions() {
        return myQuestions;
    }

    public void setMyQuestions(List<Question> myQuestions) {
        this.myQuestions = myQuestions;
    }
    private List<Question> myQuestions;
}
```

This is the question class

```
public class Question{

  public boolean isChosen(){
   retrun this.chosen
 }

  public void setChosen(boolean chosen){
    this.chosen  = chosen;
  }

  private boolean chosen;
}
```

And Here is the form that that handles that

```
<form method = "GET" action = "addItemsToTemplate">
    <s:iterator value = "myQuestions"  status="key" var = "questionItem">
    <s:checkbox  name = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].chosen"   label="Check Me for testing"/>        
</s:iterator>
</form>
```

this method handles the form

```
public String addItemsToTemplate(){
            List<Question>  q=  myQuestions;
            System.out.println(q);

            return "success";
        }
```

Upon submission, the `myQuestions` returns a `null`. why is that? 
I want to identify if the corresponding question has been chosen.

Comment: I'm not a Struts 2 user, but seems that you're misusing the `<s:iterator>` tag. Please refer to [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/) to fix you code accordingly.

Comment: Your `myQuestions` variable returns `null` since you haven't initialized it anywhere (as shown in answer).

Comment: but it has been initialized from another action

Comment: Again, I'm not a Struts 2 user. Also, we can't just imagine what other classes/methods you have in order to make your project to work. Be sure to post the relevant and necessary code piece that can help people here to read, understand and replicate your problem in order to provide you good answers.

Comment: Struts 2 is action based framework which means what was initialised previously is gone in a new request. So you must store your objects somewhere (DB? Session?) to reuse them with other actions.

Comment: @LukaszLenart You are right Struts is an action based framework that is what stands in the tag description that is better taking your requests and put it into action.

Answer (score 0):

where are you populating the myQuestions on the Action Layer.

If you are not populating it anywhere then when the myQuestions variable is encountered on the JSP it is empty/null due to which i think the flow will not go inside your iterator loop.

```
<s:iterator value = "myQuestions"  status="key" var = "questionItem">
    <s:checkbox  name = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].chosen"   label="Check Me for testing"/>        
</s:iterator>
```

Now if you submit the form, surely the myQuestions object is not mapped with anything from the JSP and thus is coming as null

Comment: I am populating it somewhere in the same Action class from a different method.