# Struts2 Iterator OGNL index not working

Tags: java, struts2, iterator, jstl, ognl

I have this iterator.

```
<s:iterator value = "myQuestions"  status="key">

<s:property value="%{#key.index}" />
<h1><s:property value = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].question"/></h1>

</s:iterator>
```

When the iterator iterate on this

```
<s:property value="%{#key.index}" />
```

it displays the proper index. but when I add `%{#key.index}`  in this

```
 <h1><s:property value = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].question"/></h1>
```

it doesn't  display the element who is at that certain indice.

so let's say the current index is at 0.

when I do this `<s:property value = "myQuestions[%{#key.index}].question"/>` it does not display anything. but when I hard code it.

```
<s:property value = "myQuestions[0].question"/> it displays the proper item. what am I missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking the evaluation. It should be closer to:

```
%{myQuestions[#key.index].question}
```

It's quite redundant, though, since you're iterating, and each object in the collection will be pushed onto the stack, so all you need to refer to is `question`.

You can also use the `var` attribute if you need to name each object.

Consider checking out the iterator tag docs.

Comment: where exactly would I insert that?

Comment: when I resubmit the form.  will it repopulate the list?

Comment: @user962206 ... In the only place you try to access a  specific question?

Comment: @user962206 What form?! You're displaying a value, that has nothing to do with forms.

Comment: I'll just ask that in another question. putting it here is out of context.

Comment: Its here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650002/populate-user-defined-objects-from-a-list-from-the-jsp/15650245#15650245